# Why will Anaconda Navigator not launch and how do I fix access is denied?

Tags: python, anaconda

I am taking over a computer at work where another user had installed Anaconda.  When I launch Anaconda Prompt, it just says Access is denied.  When I try to open Anaconda Navigator nothing happens.  I have read some people uninstalled and reinstalled Anaconda.  I dont want to do this as some of the other users that used the computer have conda environments already setup.

Comment: this will help [Installing for multiple users](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/multi-user/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually that means that Anaconda was installed with administrative rights, `Install for all users`.

Ask your IT to execute the following commands or reinstall Ananconda `Only for this user`

https://docs.anaconda.com/ae-notebooks/admin-guide/user-mgmt/add-remove-admin/